# Using DTW to align video sequences

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I have to match one video sequence with the other. The actions and motions of the two videos are similar, since the video that I'm matching with is doing the exact same movement as the other one. And currently, I'm leaning towards using dynamic time warping(DTW) to align those two videos, but I have some trouble coming up with an idea to do so. So I'm wondering if you guys have any source code that I can work with or any ideas on how to dissect this problem. Thank you

Comment: DTW is a pretty cool thing - but I feel, that an decisive question will be: How to compute the "distance" between to image samples? This is the foundation for any alignment.

Comment: forgot to mention. Since in the video I'll track human pose, so I have the coordinates to work with. I was thinking of neutralizing the 3D skeleton first and using the coordinates with the joints to apply into dtw. But still kinda loss on the steps

Answer (score 0):

a starting point would be to understand DTW [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emueen/DTW.pdf)